# How do I install the evasi0n jailbreak tool?

Tags: software-installation, ipod

I'm trying to jailbreak my iPod touch with a tool called [evasi0n](http://evasi0n.com/).

I have downloaded the package, but I have no idea how to run/install it. I am trying to do this on a Dell Latitude D830 with an Intel Core 2 Duo and 4GB of ram.

Comment: What does this have to do with ubuntu?

Comment: There is a Linux version of the tool that I am trying to make work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Where did you get it from? What version are you running? etc

Comment: @Magpie FYI [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/jailbreak-ios-60-and-61-devices-under.html) publishing an article on Monday may have something to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another way to install evasi0n on Ubuntu rather than downloading from the website. This way is a bit better (In my opinion) as you will get updates for it in the Software Updater every time the team updates the tool.

To install Evasi0n in Ubuntu 12.10/12.04,  open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/evasion
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evasion-linux
```

Then, to open it, go to the dash, and type `evasi0n`.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out:
Go into the downloads folder, and extract it. Go into the folder, and the one that says evasi0n, click on it, and a window will open up. Just choose "open with terminal".  A terminal window will pop up, and then the evasi0n window will.